# How to run nodemon and parcel watch in one command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I would love to start nodemon and the watch:js script in just one command? Run both scripts in just one script command - is this possible? The other solutions found didn't worked for me ...

```json
// package.json

"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it like so:
// install a node package called "concurrently"

npm install concurrently

After that create a new script in your package.json file:

"dadScript": "concurrently \"npm run childScript1\" \"npm run childScript2\""

For me it works to start simultaneously react client server and node-express server

Comment: thx, for your fast anwswer.

i tried to get nodemon running with conurrently with: "dev": "concurrently \"nodemon server.js\"". But after i changed something I always run into EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000 Error ...

Comment: It worked! i had to restart my pc. dunno why xD

Comment: wouldn't it work only sometimes, when the parcel build process finishes before nodemon starts?